# How do I get the extra side buttons on my Intellimouse Explorer working?

Tags: usb, mouse, input-devices

How do I get the extra side buttons (6 and 7) on my Intellimouse Explorer working?

Comment: Are you able to bind these extra keys to anything under Keyboard Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with it I guess. At least with Compiz and CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager) there are some things you can use those buttons for.

Comment: How you do that?